# vb.net code to enlarge font size, font name and do page setup in ms.excell

Tags: vb.net, excel-2007

I am creating an excel report from vb.net. Now it works. But i realize that the apparent does not make sense. I just want enlarge some font size and change font name plus setting up the page to fit my receipt printer (Epson TM-T88IV).

what should i do ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First manually set everything up bit by bit until it all fits nicely on your receipt printer.

Once you have everything just the way you want:

1. Generate a new, plain copy of the report.
2. Start recording a macro
3. Manually replicate the changes that you did in your practice sheet onto your macro recording sheet.
4. Stop recording the Macro, and press Alt-F11 to get to the VB that was generated.
5. Use the relevant lines of the generated macro to see what you need to add to your report generation code.

Comment: but the OP is generating the report from VB.NET...recording a macro gives you VBA code, which is not easily compatible with .NET

Comment: True,  but the macro will show the OP exactly which properties, etc. to set...  that's the hard part.   Adapting the syntax is relatively trivial in comparison.

Comment: could you explain more detail? (i am a beginner in vb.net)

Comment: Once you follow the steps above, you will get a list of all of the instructions that Excel needs to accomplish the formatting.

In your VB.NET project you will have a reference to the Excel Interop. Perform the same operations as in the macro against the corresponding Excel Interop Object.